DraftClientException: The request had some invalid properties Activity ID: 503d3748-34c3-4395-b784-278b19a089af
I am trying to deploy a custom alert but getting error as :-
DraftClientException: The request had some invalid properties Activity ID: 503d3748-34c3-4395-b784-278b19a089af.

I am calling the below from the yaml pipeline :-
- ${{if eq(parameters.CustomAlert, 'true')}}:
        - template: ../Monitor-Pipeline/generic-templates/create-scheduled-query-alerts-${{ parameters.environment }}.yml
          parameters:
            ServiceConnectionName: ${{variables.AzureServiceConnection}}
            SubscriptionId: ${{variables.SubscriptionID}}
            ResourceGroupName: ${{ variables.ResourceGroupName }}
            ResourceGroupLocation: westeurope
            AlertName: 'Custom-para-alert'
            AlertDescription: ${{variables.BusinessCI}}
            WorkspaceName: ${{variables.LogAnalyticsWorkspaceName}}
            ActionGroupName: ${{variables.ActionGroupName}}
            customAlert: '${{parameters.customAlert}}'

where in all these variables are being passed on from separate environment.yml file.
which in turn is calling ../Monitor-Pipeline/generic-templates/create-scheduled-query-alerts-${{ parameters.environment }}.yml
 steps:
 - ${{ if eq(parameters.customAlert, 'true') }}:
  - task: AzureResourceManagerTemplateDeployment@3
displayName: 'logcustom'
inputs:
  deploymentScope: 'Resource Group'
  azureResourceManagerConnection: ${{ parameters.ServiceConnectionName }}
  subscriptionId: ${{ parameters.SubscriptionId }}
  action: 'Create Or Update Resource Group'
  resourceGroupName: ${{ parameters.ResourceGroupName }}
  location: ${{ parameters.ResourceGroupLocation }}
  templateLocation: 'Linked artifact'
  csmFile: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/Monitor-Pipeline/generic-templates/armtemplates/template.scheduled-email-alert.json'
  csmParametersFile: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/Monitor-Pipeline/generic-templates/armtemplates/param.customlog.json'
  overrideParameters: '-alertName ${{ parameters.AlertName }} -alertDescription ${{ parameters.AlertDescription }} -workspaceName ${{ parameters.WorkspaceName }} -actionGroupName ${{ parameters.ActionGroupName}} -location ${{ parameters.ResourceGroupLocation }} -subscriptionId ${{ parameters.SubscriptionId }} -resourceGroupName ${{ parameters.ResourceGroupName }}'
  deploymentMode: 'Incremental'

